# In Java, how do you tokenize a string that contains the delimiter in the tokens?

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

Let's say I have the string:

```
String toTokenize = "prop1=value1;prop2=String test='1234';int i=4;;prop3=value3";
```

I want the tokens:

1. prop1=value1
2. prop2=String test='1234';int i=4;
3. prop3=value3

For backwards compatibility, I have to use the semicolon as a delimiter. I have tried wrapping code in something like CDATA:

```
String toTokenize = "prop1=value1;prop2=<![CDATA[String test='1234';int i=4;]]>;prop3=value3";
```

But I can't figure out a regular expression to ignore the semicolons that are within the cdata tags.

I've tried escaping the non-delimiter:

```
String toTokenize = "prop1=value1;prop2=String test='1234'\\;int i=4\\;;prop3=value3";
```

But then there is an ugly mess of removing the escape characters.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to use an other format. If you have a control on the format, why don't you use for example the JSON format.

Comment: This is a classical CSV file parsing where a field can contain the separator. It is commonly handled by *quoting* the field inside double quotes: `String toTokenize = "prop1=value1;\"prop2=String test='1234';int i=4;\";prop3=value3";`. Unfortunately the JDK contains no CSV Parser, but if [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) is an option, that becomes a possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match either `<![CDATA...]]>` or any char other than `;`, 1 or more times, to match the values. To match the keys, you may use a regular `\w+` pattern:

```
(\w+)=((?:<!\[CDATA\[.*?]]>|[^;])+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1vq0aw/1).

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `=` - a `=` sign
- `((?:<!\[CDATA\[.*?]]>|[^;])+)` - Group 1: one or more sequences of

  - `<!\[CDATA\[.*?]]>` - a `<![CDATA[...]]>` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `[^;]` - any char but `;`

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ZOmgow):

```
String rx = "(\\w+)=((?:<!\\[CDATA\\[.*?]]>|[^;])+)";
String s = "prop1=value1;prop2=<![CDATA[String test='1234';int i=4;]]>;prop3=value3";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " => " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Results:

```
prop1 => value1
prop2 => <![CDATA[String test='1234';int i=4;]]>
prop3 => value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite:

- All your tokens start with `prop`
- There is no `prop` in the file other than the beginning of a token

I'd just do a replace of all `;prop` by `~prop`

Then your string becomes:

```
"prop1=value1~prop2=String test='1234';int i=4~prop3=value3";
```

You can then tokenize using the `~` delimiter

Comment: What if there is `~` in the CDATA contents?

Comment: then you pick something else .. `~d!b~` for example

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about the new token already appearing _(as you can pick pretty much whatever)_, but would be worried if one of the values could contain `;prop#=`

Comment: @phflack Indeed, in this case it wouldn't work, but I wrote it as a prerequisite to my answer.

Comment: I do not see it as a prerequisite, did you mean to edit that in?

Comment: I wrote: `If all your tokens start with propx=`

Comment: Ho right, I see what you mean, sorry. Yes wouldn't work

Comment: That is certainly a prerequisite, as is that values do not contain `;prop#=`

Comment: @phflack I added it